# 2-fibrations in terms of comma categories

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory

Fibrations of 2-categories and bicategories were defined by Hermida and Bakovic, respectively, and their Grothendieck construction was studied by Buckley in [Fibred 2-categories and bicategories](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jpaa.2013.11.002).  Fibrations of bicategories $E\to B$ correspond to weak 3-functors $B^{\rm coop} \to \rm Bicat$, while split fibrations of 2-categories correspond to strict 3-functors $B^{\rm coop} \to 2\rm Cat$.

These definitions of fibration for 2-categories and bicategories are written explicitly in terms of cartesian liftings.  However, 1-fibrations also have other characterizations.  In particular, a functor of 1-categories $p:E\to B$ is a fibration just when the induced map $E \to (B/p)$ to the comma category has a right adjoint over $B$, with identity unit.

Are there analogous characterizations of 2-dimensional fibrations?  In particular, I would like to know how strictness properties of the fibration correspond to strictness properties of the comma category and the adjunction?

I would presume that if the comma bicategory and the adjunction are all fully weak, one would obtain essentially the notion of fibration of bicategories, although I haven't seen even this written down, and one might have to be careful to end up with the version of the latter with strict liftings (rather than a "Street" version where the codomains of lifts are only equivalent to the starting point).  And in order to get a split 2-fibration one would presumably need the adjoint to be a strict algebra for some monad induced by the comma categories, as in the 1-categorical case, although even here it's not immediately clear to me that you want the comma category and the adjunction to be totally strict.

I'm most interested in what sort of fibration of 2-categories corresponds to a "$\rm Gray$-enriched fibration in $\rm Gray$", meaning that $p$ is a strict 2-functor; $(B/p)$ is a "pseudonatural comma 2-category", coming with a universal pseudonatural transformation, and satisfying a universal property expressed by an isomorphism of hom-2-categories; and the adjunction consists of a pair of 2-functors with pseudonatural unit and counit, in the "slice $\rm Gray$-category" whose morphisms are triangles commuting up to pseudonatural equivalence, satisfying the triangle identities up to isomorphism.

Section 4.2 in Buckley's paper suggests that perhaps all of these comma categories should be *(op)lax*, in that they come with a universal *oplax* natural transformation.  For instance, his Remark 4.2.6 claims that such oplax comma categories are "free fibrations" in a bicategorical sense.  I'm most interested in the case of $(2,1)$-categories where this difference vanishes, but if it makes for a cleaner answer feel free to use lax or oplax commas.

Comment: I will expand this into an answer when I have the time, but let me note now that the cleanest "Chevalley criteria" for 2-dimensional fibrations use double categories. E.g., a 2-functor $F \colon A \to B$ is a "fibered 2-category" in Buckley's definition (which is slightly stronger than Hermida's definition) iff the double functor $Sq(F) \colon Sq(A) \to Sq(B)$ is a fibration in the 2-category of double categories, pseudo double functors, and vertical natural transformations, i.e. when the double functor $Sq(A)//Sq(A) \to Sq(B)//Sq(F)$ has a right adjoint pseudo double functor.

Comment: (Where $Sq$ denotes the "double category of squares" construction, and $//$ denotes the "comma double category" construction.)

Comment: @AlexanderCampbell I look forward to the expanded answer!